# nodejs: Start server and look for string "server started at 127.0.0.1:8000" and then start the tests

Tags: node.js, server, promise, stdout

I am starting the server from my NodeJS script and then want to execute my tests. But when I start the server the server start process doesn't return as it is running and control is not returned back. The server starts and the app can be accessed on http://localhost:8000.

trying to start the server and then monitor the stdout of the runserver process and look for a match "Starting server at 127.0.0.1:8000" and then proceed to run the tests.
Is there any way it can be done using exec or spawn node command and then monitor for the required string to start my tests ?

Based on previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68848963/nodejs-how-to-wait-for-server-start-at-http-localhost8000?noredirect=1&lq=1) where starting test on polling when Http://localhost:8000 is up and running.

Solution I am looking for is Starting test based on stdout data string matches - "Starting development server".

Comment: you should prob link back to [prev question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68848963/nodejs-how-to-wait-for-server-start-at-http-localhost8000?noredirect=1&lq=1), or add the code you have tried, then it will give more context and may not incur a bunch of downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use spawn and look for the string, then run your tests, monitor SIGTERM and SIGINT, then pass it along to the child.

```
const {
  spawn
} = require('child_process')

// your cmd to start the server, possibly spawn('python', ['manage.py', 'startserver'])
const server = spawn('node', ['server.js'])

let timer = null
server.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`)

  // look for the string in stdout
  if (data.includes('Starting development server')) {

    console.log('Commencing tests in 2 seconds')
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Run tests')

      // ...

      // tests complete
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('Tests completed, shutting down server')
        server.kill('SIGINT')
      }, 2000)
    }, 2000)
  }
})

server.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  clearTimeout(timer)
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`)
});

server.on('close', (code) => {
  clearTimeout(timer)
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});

process
  .on('SIGTERM', shutdown('SIGTERM'))
  .on('SIGINT', shutdown('SIGINT'))
  .on('uncaughtException', shutdown('uncaughtException'))

function shutdown(signal) {
  return (err) => {
    console.log(`\n${signal} signal received.`)

    if (err && err !== signal) console.error(err.stack || err)

    console.log('Killing child process.')
    server.kill(signal)
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
node spawn.js 
stdout: Starting development server http://localhost:8000

Commencing tests in 2 seconds
Run tests
Tests completed, shutting down server
stdout: 
SIGINT signal received.

stdout: Closing HTTP server.

stdout: HTTP server closed.

child process exited with code 0
```

The test server script used was the following, note above that it's passing back the SIGINT signal it received.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

const server = app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Starting development server http://localhost:${port}`))


process
  .on('SIGTERM', shutdown('SIGTERM'))
  .on('SIGINT', shutdown('SIGINT'))
  .on('uncaughtException', shutdown('uncaughtException'))

function shutdown(signal) {
  return (err) => {
    console.log(`\n${signal} signal received.`)

    if (err && err !== signal) console.error(err.stack || err)

    console.log('Closing HTTP server.')
    server.close(() => {
      console.log('HTTP server closed.')
      //
      process.exit(err && err !== signal ? 1 : 0)
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lawrence, the solution worked. I had to do few changes as I wanted to call this from my tests. so I created a function and added timeout logic and then calling from my tests to start the server and then when test finishes, calling to kill/stop the server as another function.